# Why doesn't my regular expression collapse groups of newlines?

Tags: regex, perl, newline

I have the following regex to try to reduce groups of newlines:

```
s/(\n|\r\n|\n\r)(\n|\r\n|\n\r)(\n|\r\n|\n\r)+/\n\n/gmi;
```

It started out as:

```
s/\n\n(\n)+/\n\n/gmi
```

I am looking to reduce the number of newlines that are continuous to a maximum of two in a row (just trying to do some cleanup on some files that I am importing for an internal wiki).
The data has several lines of CRLF's spread throughout it (Windows data files).
Yet, it doesn't seem to work.

What am I doing wrong? Here is a sample where it is coming out wrong:

**Starts off as:**

```
added missing options for Menu and toolbar positioning</p>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

**I am stripping HTML tags, so it ends up like this:**

```
added missing options for Menu and toolbar positioning
```

**Then I apply the regex and it comes out as:**

```
added missing options for Menu and toolbar positioning
```

Comment: Please see my suggestion in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965427/why-doesnt-my-regular-expression-collapse-groups-of-newlines/965569#965569 showing *how* you can best show your input/output in a way that we can see what it actually consists of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try also matching any other whitespace left over around those newlines:

```
s/(\r?\n[ \t]*){2,}/\n\n/g;
```

Comment: This reduces a set of 6 to a set of 4... I'm not sure why it's not reducing it to just 2?

Comment: Useless use of /m; /m only affects what ^ and $ match.

Comment: @Daemonic: works for me: perl -we'$x="\r\n" x 6; $x=~s/(\r?\n){2,}/\n\n/gmi; use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq=1;print Dumper $x'
$VAR1 = "\n\n";

Comment: /i is also unnecessary :) Fixed.

Comment: @Daemonic: You have whitespace in the lines. Try my latest version.

Comment: The whitespace addition seemed to work.  I also noticed that one of the extra enters was coming from a statement a bit further along (I thought I had checked all the modifying code, but I missed a section).

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to be having trouble applying the answers given, maybe you could show us some of your actual data, with

```
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
print Dumper $slurped_file;
```

You may also want to try one pass removing any \r characters, and then your original newline-only substitution.

Comment: Starts off as:
<pre>
added missing options for Menu and toolbar positioning&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;/div&gt;

&lt;/body&gt;

&lt;/html&gt;
</pre>

I am stripping HTML tags, so it ends up like this:
<pre>
added missing options for Menu and toolbar positioning





</pre>

Then I apply the regex and it comes out as:
<pre>
added missing options for Menu and toolbar positioning



</pre>

Comment: hmmm... pre's don't work out in comments. I'll add that to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

did you try matching your multiple groups like this?

```
(\r\n){2,}/\n\n
```